# Need help in Refining Rules for Importing Data from Excel Spread Sheet into the Protege 5.5 using Cellfie Plugin

Tags: excel, owl, semantic-web, protege, import-from-excel

I'm working with ontologies and I've to import data from Excel spreadsheets into Protege. I'm using Cellfie plugin to import data but facing a problem.
There are three classes "Consumer", "Energy", and "Date" having Object Properties as below

```
1) "Consumer" consumes "Energy" OR "Energy" isConsumedBy "Consumer"
2) "Energy" isConsumedOn "Date"
```

Here is my spreadsheet
[SpreadSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsfw5.png), The details are given below:

```
1) Row 1 (A1-F1) represents the dates on which energy has been consumed.
2) A2-G6 represents the consumed amount of energy
3) Column H represents Consumers who consume Energy.
4) Column I represents either Consumer is fair or not. (I'm not concerned with this column.)
```

Here are the rules which I tried:

1)

```
Individual: @H*
Types: consumer
(Start column: H, End column: H, Start row: 2, End row: 6)
```

2)

```
Individual: @**
Types: date
(Start column: A, End column: G, Start row: 1, End row: 1)
```

3)

```
Individual: @**
Types: energy
Facts: isConsumedBy @H*
Facts: isConsumedOn @*1
(Start column: A, End column: G, Start row: 2, End row: 6)
```

The problem which I'm facing is that if there are the two same consumptions such as "0" by two different consumers and on two different dates, there is only one individual of "0" which is linked with Date and Consumer twice, like

```
"isConsumed by A"
"isConsumed by B"
"isConsumedOn y"
"isConsumedOn Z".
```

Kindly tell me how I can solve it by refining my rules?
Or
Is there any other way to define the rules more precisely?
Thank you so much!

Comment: `Individual: @**(mm:Location)`. See https://github.com/protegeproject/mapping-master/wiki/MappingMasterDSL#basic-reference-resolution. Probably you also need something like `Facts: hasValue @**(xsd:float)`.

Comment: Thanks dear.
Should I add (mm:Location) in all rules where I'm creating INDIVIDUAL ?
And what it does ?